# Getting Internet to run with Inspiron 1525 in Linux Mint 11

Tags: internet-connection, dell-inspiron, linux-mint, broadcom

I have tried installing the drivers with that one click option they promote but it doesn't pull up the broadcom drivers it needs.

Answer (score 1):

Had a huge problem with that way back when. The easy way out is to go and buy another WiFi adapter to use over USB. But that would be ugly.

Try plugging the computer into an Ethernet port (you have tried that, right?). Then follow [this guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Driver/bcm43xx#b43%20-%20Internet%20access). It's basically what the utility does but since you're doing it yourself it'll be easier to see what (if anything) goes wrong.

Have fun.

Comment: I have tried that. It doesn't even recognize the ethernet.

Comment: Is your Ethernet a Broadcom thing too?

Comment: Did you try [this guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Driver/bcm43xx#b43%20-%20No%20Internet%20access)?